# Get user, but do not return 401 with Express Passport + JWT middleware

Tags: javascript, express, jwt, passport.js

I'm authenticating calls to my express API using passport. I have a pretty standard setup:

```
/* Passport Setup */

const jwtOptions = {
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('Bearer'),
    secretOrKey: config.auth.passport.key,
}

passport.use(
    'jwt',
    new JWT.Strategy(jwtOptions, (payload, done) => {
        console.log('Using JWT Strategy')
        User.findOne({ email: payload.email }, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return done(err, false)
            }
            if (user) {
                done(null, user)
            } else {
                done(null, false)
            }
        })
    }),
)

/* Middleware */

const checkToken = passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false })

const logAuthInfo = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.headers)
    console.log(req.user)

}

/* Routes */

app.use(passport.initialize())

app.use('/graphql', checkToken, logAuthInfo, graphqlHTTP(graphQLConfig))
// other REST routes, including login
```

My login route returns a JWT, and when a request is made to `/graphql` with this token, everything works. But, an unauthenticated request (with no token) returns a 401. What I'd like to do differently is use the `checkToken` middleware on **all** requests, assigning `req.user` to either the authenticated user data or `false`. I'd then handle any authorization elsewhere.

When I make a request without a token, I don't see 'Using JWT Strategy' log to the console, so that middleware isn't even running.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out shortly after posting this. For anyone coming here with the same question -- the solution is not using `passport-jwt` to achieve this, but rather the underlying `jsonwebtoken`.

My working middleware now looks like:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const PassportJwt = require('passport-jwt')

const getUserFromToken = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = PassportJwt.ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('Bearer')(req)
    jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            req.user = false
            next()
            return
        }
        req.user = decoded
        next()
    })
}

app.use(getUserFromToken)
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP(graphQLConfig))


// Elsewhere, in my GraphQL resolvers

const userQuery = (obj, args, request, info) => {
        //                    ^^^^^^^
        // I've also seen this parameter referred to as 'context'
    console.log(request.user) // either 'false' or the serialized user data

        if (req.user) {
            // do things that this user is allowed to do...
        } else {
           // user is not logged in, do some limited things..
       } 
}
```